# Is there a built-in Git tool to copy a single file to all branches?

Tags: git

In Git, there are a few files (like `.gitignore` and `.gitattributes`) that I'd like to update occasionally, and update all copies in a repo. I can use something like the following:

```bash
git branch -r | grep -v '>' | awk -F'/' '{print $2}' | while read b
do

    git checkout $b
    git pull
    cp /path/to/some/file/.gitattributes .
    git commit -a -m "update attributes"
    git push

done
```

Is there any **built-in** tool in Git made for syncing files globally?  I was hoping there was a simpler way to sync global config changes.

Comment: You could track them in a separate branch and merge that branch into others.

Comment: hmm, that's an interesting idea...

Comment: This is too broad and opinion based, but for what it's worth, you can try doing fast-foward merges locally (without having to checkout branches), using `git fetch . <source>:<destination>` syntax.

Comment: Thanks... I'll have to try that as well. Really I suppose there is no built-in tool in git made for syncing files globally.

Comment: Another thing I might recommend is setting up the code so that it looks in a single subdirectory for configuration files, then make that directory a Git submodule.  It allows you to do all the regular things described above (merging branches, etc) but your main project's history graph looks cleaner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's a single built-in command to do this (as far as I'm aware), you're going to have to just continue scripting this together with a bunch of other Git commands (as of Git version 2.0).

Comment: Thanks!  I just wasn't sure if I was missing some obvious tool.

Comment: @user1389596 hey, who knows, maybe it will turn out that I'm completely and utterly wrong.